# Binary Insertion Sort Algorithm Duplicate Output

Tags: algorithm, pascal

```
  for i:= 1 to 5 do
      begin
        temp := data[i];
        bawah := 1;
        atas := i;
        k:=i;   
        while (bawah < atas) do
          begin
          tengah := (bawah + atas) div 2;

          if (temp <= data[tengah]) then
              atas := tengah
          else
              bawah := tengah + 1;
          end;

          while (k > atas) do
            begin
              data[k] := data[k - 1];
              data[atas] := temp;
              k-=1;
            end;
      end;
```

problem is, array ordered are not entirely
the result is like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing the following assignment too early:

```
data[atas] := temp;
```

In a next iteration of the loop, the value of `k-1` will become `atas`, and so the wrong value will be copied to `data[k]`, leading to duplicates and loss of the original value that was in `data[atas]`.

So move that line out of the loop: it needs to be executed only when the shift operation has been completed:

```
      while (k > atas) do
        begin
          data[k] := data[k - 1];
          k-=1;
        end;
      data[atas] := temp;
```